# Probability of Photoelectric Interactions

Tags: radiation, photoelectric-effect, gamma-rays

I have am currently reading Radiation Detection and Measurement, by Gleen F.Knoll, and in chapter 2 page 49, he talks about the probability of the photoelectric interaction as: $$\tau \approx C \frac{Z^n}{E_{\gamma}^{3.5}}$$ and say's that 'exponent n varies between 4 and 5 over the gamma-ray energy region of interest'.

But what dose the actually mean? I can't quite picture what he is saying, can someone put this in to context if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> exponent n varies between 4 and 5 over the gamma-ray energy region of
>   interest

It says that, for gamma rays (high energy EM radiation), the photoelectric interaction (interaction of a gamma ray photon with an atom resulting in the emission of an electron) is more likely to occur in materials with high atomic number, Z (number of protons in the nucleus).

More specifically, the probability of photoelectric interaction is proportional to $Z^n$, where $n$, the power or exponent, varies between $4$ and $5$.

As an example, according to this formula, the probability of the photoelectric interaction of gamma rays with lead (atomic number $82$) should be $16 (2^4)$ to $32 (2^5)$ times greater than the probability of photoelectric interaction of the same gamma rays with niobium (atomic number $41$).